# WriteInt() does not seem to be functioning

Tags: java, binary, persistence

I have a function designed to write the contents of a text file into a binary file. The code works fine when overwrite is true, but when overwrite is false it stops on line 80 (oldCount = binaryInput.readInt();) and throws a null exception. I'm new to Java so I'm probably doing something obvious. Here is the stack trace: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at Converter.fromText(Converter.java:80)
    at Tron_Class.main(Tron_Class.java:19)

```
    public static int fromText (String textRefference, String binaryRefference, boolean overwrite){

    if(!(new File(binaryRefference).exists()))overwrite = true;
    BufferedReader input;
    ObjectOutputStream output;
    ObjectInputStream binaryInput;
    int count = 0;

    try{
        input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textRefference));
        String[] data = null;
        int oldCount = 0;
        if(!overwrite){
            binaryInput = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(binaryRefference));
            oldCount = binaryInput.readInt();
            data = new String[oldCount];
            int i;
            for(i = 0;i < oldCount; i++){

                data[i] = binaryInput.readUTF();

            }

        }

        output = new 
                ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(binaryRefference));

        String sentinel = input.readLine();
        String[] data2 = new String[1500];
        while(!sentinel.equalsIgnoreCase("end")){

            System.out.println(sentinel + "   has been recorded");
            data2[count] = sentinel;
            sentinel = input.readLine();
            count++;

        }

        if(!overwrite)count += oldCount;

        output.writeInt(count);

        if(!overwrite){

            int i;
            for(i = 0; i < oldCount;i++){

                output.writeUTF(data[i]);

            }

        }

        int i = 0;
        for(; i < count;i++){

            output.writeUTF(data2[i]);

        }

        output.close();
        input.close();

    }

    catch(Exception e){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("\n hit ENTER to exit.");
        in.nextLine();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Which one is line 80?

Comment: Have you considered using DataInput/OutputStream as you don't appear to need an ObjectInput/OutputStream?

Comment: Sorry. I thought it would number them. Line 80 is: oldCount = binaryInput.readInt();.

Comment: Why do you set `input` twice if override is true?

Comment: Can you include the Stack trace because I suspect the error is that you have a corrupt file, not a null value on that line.

Comment: BTW If you were to use ObjectOutputStream, a simpler solution would be to write a `List<String>` as a single object.

Comment: What is the "Stack trace"?

Comment: When you get an exception, you see a message followed by a dump of the stack showing you each method you are in and which line was being run. This is normally printed using `e.printStackTrace()` and it is printed by default if you don't catch it.  Without this information you can't be sure where the error occurred.

Comment: The stack trace is: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@33909752

Comment: That's not what you get from `e.printStackTrace();` That's which you get from `System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());` As you can see that the later isn't very useful.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse. How would I retrieve the stack trace then?

Comment: You would add `e.printStackTrace();` to your Java code, regardless of which IDE you are using. This is why I keep mentioning `e.printStackTrace();` in the hope you will add `e.printStackTrace();` to your code ;) You can add `e.printStackTrace();` in your debugger but I you would do this only if you couldn't add `e.printStackTrace();` to you code.

Comment: This is my new catch block. What do I do now?
'catch(Exception e){
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   e.getStackTrace();
   in.nextLine();
   System.exit(0);
  }'

Comment: Note that `getStackTrace` and `printStackTrace` are different methods of course and they don't do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This loop is incorrect.

```
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < count;i++){
```

The problem is that `count` is the total number of Strings not just the number in this `data2` array. As soon as you attempt to `writeUTF(null)` it should blow up.

A simpler solution is to not modify the `count` in the first place but instead write

```
output.writeInt(oldCount + count);
```

Then the loop above will have the right `count`

Comment: That didn't fix the issue. It still blows up on the line "oldCount = binaryInput.readInt();".

Comment: @OsmuimShield how do you know which line it is without looking at the stack trace? In your debugger can see that `binaryInput` is `null`?

Comment: I did it without the stack trace by using break points to find where it jumped to the catch block.

Comment: I found the stack trace. I think.

java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
 at Converter.fromText(Converter.java:80)
 at Tron_Class.main(Tron_Class.java:19)

Comment: @OsmuimShield So you have a corrupt file.